Global virtual trust online bank
Anyone who knows the existence of a virtual bank called global virtual trust and Is it real and safe?
This bank is asking for some money for international transfer

You can't even find them on Google with that name, that's not a good sign. But an even worse sign is: why do you need to do an international transfer that involves them? I suppose someone told you that there's money for you on an account held at this "bank"? Sorry, there's no money. But they would like yours, and probably all your details as well.


This bank is asking for some money for international transfer

Anybody charging you money to get your money can't be trusted.

Anyone who knows the existence of a virtual bank called global virtual
trust and Is it real and safe?

I have never heard of them, but in light of the request for money to get money, I wouldn't trust them.

Charging for transfers (especially international) is normal, the red flag is if they are asking for that money as a separate transaction instead of an extra cost baked into the transfer. I think this answer would be improved by making that distinction.
